# How to have only active tab its background color set

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm trying to get AJAX tabs working. Problem with the current code is it doesn't set style for an active tab.

May be I need to tackle this with some javascript code but don't really know where to start.

HTML

```js
$("h2").addClass("white");
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // load index page when the page loads
        $("#response").html("DEFAULT");
        $("#page1").click(function () {
            // load home page on click
            $("#response").html("<h2> Welcome </h2><p>Sed porttitor lectus nibh. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. <br/> Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>");
        });
        $("#page2").click(function () {
            // load about page on click
            $("#response").html("TESTING 2");
        });
        $("#page3").click(function () {
            // load contact form onclick
            $("#response").html("TESTING 3");
        });
        $("#page4").click(function () {
            // load contact form onclick
            $("#response").html("TESTING 4");
        });
        $("#page5").click(function () {
            // load contact form onclick
            $("#response").html("TESTING 5");
        });
    });
```

```css
li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 2px;

}
li a {
   
    padding: 4px;
    color:#0086ca;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.white {
    color: green;
}

.contentarea {
    margin-top: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 40px 50px;
    background-color: #0086ca;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 24px;
}

/* -------------------------------- 

Multi steps indicator 

-------------------------------- */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-multi-steps {
    /* reset style */
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .cd-multi-steps li {
    position: relative;
    float: none;
    margin: 0.4em 40px 0.4em 0;
  }
  .cd-multi-steps li:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .cd-multi-steps li::after {
    /* this is the line connecting 2 adjacent items */
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    height: 4px;
    background: #edeff0;
    /* reset style */
    margin: 0;
  }
  .cd-multi-steps li.visited::after {
    background-color: #96c03d;
  }
  .cd-multi-steps li > *, .cd-multi-steps li.current > * {
    position: relative;
    color: #2c3f4c;
  }

  .cd-multi-steps.custom-separator li::after {
    /* reset style */
    height: 4px;
    background: #edeff0;
  }

  .cd-multi-steps.text-center li::after {
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-1px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-1px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-1px);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-1px);
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-1px);
  }
  .cd-multi-steps.text-center li > * {
    z-index: 1;
    padding: .6em 1em;
    border-radius: .25em;
    background-color: #edeff0;
  }
  .no-touch .cd-multi-steps.text-center a:hover {
    background-color: #2c3f4c;
  }
  .cd-multi-steps.text-center li.current > *, .cd-multi-steps.text-center li.visited > * {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #96c03d;
  }
  .cd-multi-steps.text-center.custom-icons li.visited a::before {
    /* change the custom icon for the visited item - check icon */
    background-position: 0 -60px;
  }

  .cd-multi-steps.text-top li, .cd-multi-steps.text-bottom li {
    width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .cd-multi-steps.text-top li::after, .cd-multi-steps.text-bottom li::after {
    /* this is the line connecting 2 adjacent items */
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    /* 40px is the <li> right margin value */
    width: calc(100% + 40px);
  }
  .cd-multi-steps.text-top li > *::before, .cd-multi-steps.text-bottom li > *::before {
    /* this is the spot indicator */
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 50%;
    right: auto;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #edeff0;
  }
  .cd-multi-steps.text-top li.visited > *::before,
  .cd-multi-steps.text-top li.current > *::before, .cd-multi-steps.text-bottom li.visited > *::before,
  .cd-multi-steps.text-bottom li.current > *::before {
    background-color: #96c03d;
  }
  .no-touch .cd-multi-steps.text-top a:hover, .no-touch .cd-multi-steps.text-bottom a:hover {
    color: #96c03d;
  }
  .no-touch .cd-multi-steps.text-top a:hover::before, .no-touch .cd-multi-steps.text-bottom a:hover::before {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(150, 192, 61, 0.3);
  }

  .cd-multi-steps.text-top li::after {
    /* this is the line connecting 2 adjacent items */
    bottom: 4px;
  }
  .cd-multi-steps.text-top li > * {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .cd-multi-steps.text-top li > *::before {
    /* this is the spot indicator */
    bottom: 0;
  }

  .cd-multi-steps.text-bottom li::after {
    /* this is the line connecting 2 adjacent items */
    top: 3px;
  }
  .cd-multi-steps.text-bottom li > * {
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
  .cd-multi-steps.text-bottom li > *::before {
    /* this is the spot indicator */
    top: 0;
  }
}
/* -------------------------------- 

Add a counter to the multi-steps indicator 

-------------------------------- */
.cd-multi-steps.count li {
  counter-increment: steps;
}

.cd-multi-steps.count li > *::before {
  content: counter(steps) " - ";
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-multi-steps.text-top.count li > *::before,
  .cd-multi-steps.text-bottom.count li > *::before {
    /* this is the spot indicator */
    content: counter(steps);
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    line-height: 26px;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    color: #ffffff;
  }

  .cd-multi-steps.text-top.count li:not(.current) em::before,
  .cd-multi-steps.text-bottom.count li:not(.current) em::before {
    /* steps not visited yet - counter color */
    color: #2c3f4c;
  }

  .cd-multi-steps.text-top.count li::after {
    bottom: 11px;
  }

  .cd-multi-steps.text-top.count li > * {
    padding-bottom: 34px;
  }

  .cd-multi-steps.text-bottom.count li::after {
    top: 11px;
  }

  .cd-multi-steps.text-bottom.count li > * {
    padding-top: 34px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav>
    <ul class="cd-multi-steps text-bottom count">
        <li class="current"><a href="#tabs-1" id="page1" class="tab">page 1</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2" id="page2" class="tab">page 2</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3" id="page3" class="tab">page 3</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-4" id="page4" class="tab">page 4</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-5" id="page5" class="tab">page 5</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="contentarea" id="response"></div>
```

How do I make active tab stand out from the rest?

Thanks.

Comment: will this work http://codepen.io/nirmalyaghosh/pen/Goyqoa?

Comment: Learn to add/remove classes  http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/

Comment: See edited answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need click for every `id`. I've simplified your code and added `.active` on click. Hope it helps.

```js
     $("h2").addClass("white");
     $(document).ready(function() {
       // load index page when the page loads
       
       var data = {
         '#tabs-1':'Testing 1',
         '#tabs-2':'Testing 2',
         '#tabs-3':'Testing 3',
         '#tabs-4':'Testing 4',
         '#tabs-5':'Testing 5'
       };
       
       $("#response").html("DEFAULT");
       
       $('.tab').click(function(){
         $('.tab').removeClass('active'); //remove .active from all
         $(this).addClass('active'); //add .active to current pressed
         href = $(this).attr('href');
         $("#response").html(data[href]);
       });

     });
```

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
li a {
  padding: 8px 4px;
  color: #0086ca;
  text-decoration: none;
}


li a.active {
  color: white;
  background:#0086ca;
}

.contentarea {
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px 50px;
  background-color: #0086ca;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.cd-multi-steps.count li {
  counter-increment: steps;
}
.cd-multi-steps.count li > *::before {
  /*content: counter(steps)" - ";*/
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-multi-steps.text-top.count li > *::before,
  .cd-multi-steps.text-bottom.count li > *::before {
    /* this is the spot indicator 
    content: counter(steps);*/
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    line-height: 26px;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  .cd-multi-steps.text-top.count li:not(.current) em::before,
  .cd-multi-steps.text-bottom.count li:not(.current) em::before {
    /* steps not visited yet - counter color */
    color: #2c3f4c;
  }
  .cd-multi-steps.text-top.count li::after {
    bottom: 11px;
  }
  .cd-multi-steps.text-top.count li > * {
    padding-bottom: 34px;
  }
  .cd-multi-steps.text-bottom.count li::after {
    top: 11px;
  }
  .cd-multi-steps.text-bottom.count li > * {
    padding-top: 34px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul class="cd-multi-steps text-bottom count">
    <li class="current"><a href="#tabs-1" id="page1" class="tab">page 1</a>

    </li>
    <li class="current"><a href="#tabs-2" id="page2" class="tab">page 2</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3" id="page3" class="tab">page 3</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-4" id="page4" class="tab">page 4</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-5" id="page5" class="tab">page 5</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="contentarea" id="response"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code it may help

use `addClass()` inside click function

```
 $("li").click(function(){
  $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass('active');

  })
 $("#page1").click(function () {
 // load home page on click
 $("#response").html("<h2> Welcome </h2><p>Sed porttitor lectus nibh. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. <br/> Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>");
$("h2").addClass("white");
        });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        // load index page when the page loads
        $("#response").html("DEFAULT");
  
  $("li").click(function(){
  $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass('active');
    
  })
        $("#page1").click(function () {
            // load home page on click
            $("#response").html("<h2> Welcome </h2><p>Sed porttitor lectus nibh. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. <br/> Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>");
           $("h2").addClass("white");
        });
        $("#page2").click(function () {
            // load about page on click
            $("#response").html("TESTING 2");
        });
        $("#page3").click(function () {
            // load contact form onclick
            $("#response").html("TESTING 3");
        });
        $("#page4").click(function () {
            // load contact form onclick
            $("#response").html("TESTING 4");
        });
        $("#page5").click(function () {
            // load contact form onclick
            $("#response").html("TESTING 5");
        });
     
    });
```

```css
li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
li a {
    padding: 4px;
    color:#0086ca;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.contentarea {
    margin-top: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 40px 50px;
    background-color: #0086ca;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 24px;
}
.cd-multi-steps.count li {
  counter-increment: steps;
}
.cd-multi-steps.count li > *::before {
  content: counter(steps) " - ";
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-multi-steps.text-top.count li > *::before,
  .cd-multi-steps.text-bottom.count li > *::before {
    /* this is the spot indicator */
    content: counter(steps);
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    line-height: 26px;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    color: #ffffff;
  }
.cd-multi-steps.text-top.count li:not(.current) em::before,
  .cd-multi-steps.text-bottom.count li:not(.current) em::before {
    /* steps not visited yet - counter color */
    color: #2c3f4c;
  }
.cd-multi-steps.text-top.count li::after {
    bottom: 11px;
  }
.cd-multi-steps.text-top.count li > * {
    padding-bottom: 34px;
  }
.cd-multi-steps.text-bottom.count li::after {
    top: 11px;
  }
.cd-multi-steps.text-bottom.count li > * {
    padding-top: 34px;
  }
}
.white{color:yellow}
li.active a{color:blue; border:1px solid;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <ul class="cd-multi-steps text-bottom count">
        <li class="current"><a href="#tabs-1" id="page1" class="tab">page 1</a>

        </li>
        <li class="current"><a href="#tabs-2" id="page2" class="tab">page 2</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3" id="page3" class="tab">page 3</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-4" id="page4" class="tab">page 4</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-5" id="page5" class="tab">page 5</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="contentarea" id="response"></div>
```